# Register ASP.NET Core JsonConverter implementations using assembly scan

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I have lots of json converters, which derive from `JsonConverter<T>`. They are in various assemblies, not just the executing assembly.

I register them like this:

```cs
services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(o => {
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new FooJsonConverter());
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new BarJsonConverter());
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new BazJsonConverter());
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new QuxJsonConverter());
    // lots more...
  });
```

I'd rather add them dynamically, using an assembly scan - the same way AutoMapper, FluentValidation, Autofac, etc., do it. I looked at their repos for the secret sauce but couldn't find it.

So I tried some basic reflection:

```cs
services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(o => {

    var jsonConverters =
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain
      .GetAssemblies()
      .SelectMany(x => x.ExportedTypes)
      .Where(x => x.BaseType != null && x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(JsonConverter<>)));

    foreach (var jsonConverter in jsonConverters)
      o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(jsonConverter) as JsonConverter);

  });
```

But that fails to start, and throws:

> FTL | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics | Application startup exception
> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceFactory -> Microsoft.AspNetCore
> .Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider -> λ:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.IActionDescriptorProvider[] -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerA
> ctionDescriptorProvider -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ApplicationModelFactory -> λ:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.IApplicationModelProvider[] -> Microsoft.AspNetC
> ore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider -> λ:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.I
> CompositeMetadataDetailsProvider.
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& hasNoDefaultCtor
> )

Note the `Cannot create an abstract class`. The base class is abstract, but I'm trying to activate the subclasses.

What is the correct way to do this? Also, is it appropriate to refer to the AppDomain, as I remember reading somewhere that that behavior has changed in aspnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o => {

  var jsonConverters =
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .Where(x => !x.IsDynamic)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ExportedTypes)
    .Where(x => x.BaseType != null)                           // is not Object, or an interface
    .Where(x => x.BaseType.IsGenericType)                     // must derive from JsonConverter<T>
    .Where(x => x.BaseType.BaseType == typeof(JsonConverter)) // exclude framework types

  foreach (var jsonConverter in jsonConverters) {
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(jsonConverter) as JsonConverter;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(instance);
  }
});
```

I'm unsure whether to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` or `AssemblyLoadContext.Default`, but this way seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just change to:

```
var jsonConverters =
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain
      .GetAssemblies()
      .SelectMany(x => x.ExportedTypes)
      .Where(x => x.BaseType != null && x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(JsonConverter)));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your notes put me in the right direction. I added a solution below.

Answer (score 2):

JsonConverter<> fullfills your condition  `x => x.BaseType != null && x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(JsonConverter<>)`.
It has base type and is assignable. Sorry ;)

U can allways check if type `.IsAbstract` and then ignore them.
Another solution is to register classes by convention (by name in this case ).I use Autofac but the method will be the same

```
  builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(serviceAssembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsSelf();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your notes put me in the right direction. I added a solution below.